# Time zone conversion while loading in snowflake from pyspark

Tags: pyspark, timezone, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am writing a data frame in snowflake using pyspark, that data frame has a column with a timestamp. I have set it in US/Eastern time zone using spark config, but when I write it to snowflake it gets converted to UTC by default. I want it to be in US/Eastern only.

What should I add in snowflake spark connector options that can fix my problem?

PS: I have tried sfOptions["sfTimezone"] = 'America/New_York', sfOptions["sfTimezone"] = 'spark'.
Both don't work :(

Answer (score 0):

Spark provides only one type of timestamp, equivalent to the Scala/Java Timestamp type. It is almost identical in behavior to the TIMESTAMP_LTZ (local time zone) data type in Snowflake. As such, when transferring data between Spark and Snowflake, Snowflake recommends using the following approaches to preserve time correctly, relative to time zones:

- Use only the TIMESTAMP_LTZ data type in Snowflake.

**Note** The default timestamp data type mapping is TIMESTAMP_NTZ (no time zone), so you must explicitly set the TIMESTAMP_TYPE_MAPPING parameter to use TIMESTAMP_LTZ.

- Set the Spark time zone to UTC and use this time zone in Snowflake (i.e. don’t set the sfTimezone option for the connector, and don’t explicitly set a time zone in Snowflake). In this scenario, TIMESTAMP_LTZ and TIMESTAMP_NTZ are effectively equivalent.

To set the time zone, add the following line to your Spark code:

```
java.util.TimeZone.setDefault(java.util.TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"))
```

If you don’t implement either of these approaches, undesired time modifications might occur. For example, consider the following scenario:

- The time zone in Spark is set to America/New_York.
- The time zone in Snowflake is set to Europe/Warsaw, which can happen by either:

1. Setting sfTimezone to Europe/Warsaw for the connector.
2. Setting sfTimezone to snowflake for the connector and setting the TIMEZONE session parameter in Snowflake to Europe/Warsaw.

- Both TIMESTAMP_NTZ and TIMESTAMP_LTZ are in use in Snowflake.

In this scenario:

1. If a value representing 12:00:00 in a TIMESTAMP_NTZ column in Snowflake is sent to Spark, this value doesn’t carry any time zone information. Spark treats the value as 12:00:00 in New York.
2. If Spark sends this value 12:00:00 (in New York) back to Snowflake to be loaded into a TIMESTAMP_LTZ column, it is automatically converted and loaded as 18:00:00 (for the Warsaw time zone).
3. If this value is then converted to TIMESTAMP_NTZ in Snowflake, the user sees 18:00:00, which is different from the original value, 12:00:00.

To summarize, Snowflake recommends strictly following at least one of these rules:

- Use the same time zone, ideally UTC, for both Spark and Snowflake.
- Use only the TIMESTAMP_LTZ data type for transferring data between Spark and Snowflake.

The behavior you see is also explained in detail [here](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/spark-connector-use.html#working-with-timestamps-and-time-zones).

Comment: Link-only answers are discouraged.  Please add context to your answer, such that the answer survives even if the link becomes broken in the future.  See https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer, https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259/201534 and many others.